# What does ‘have rather’ mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The beauty of Qingdao has rather to be seen in its waters than mountains.

It’s written by a translator, which means the original text is not English.
I wonder why did he write *has rather to be,* is it a more literary way to express something? I didn’t find much about it online so I’m asking here.

Comment: Splitting "has to" with "rather" is bad style. Better would be, "The beauty of Qingdao **is** seen in its waters rather than in its mountains." Or to capture as much of the original intent as possible, "The beauty of Qingdao **must be** seen in its waters, rather than its mountains," but that still sounds odd.

Answer (score 1):

I think the intended meaning is this:

> The beauty of Qingdao has to be seen in its waters, rather than in its mountains.

The word order could be changed to this, though it sounds a little affected:

> The beauty of Qingdao has rather to be seen in its waters, than in its mountains.

The translator has put this into the version that you cite:

> The beauty of Qingdao has rather to be seen in its waters than mountains.

I don't think "in its waters than mountains" works.

Comment: You're right when it comes to its intended meaning. Why do you say the second one reads affectedly? Since I can't feel the "unnaturalness," if that's what you mean, would you like to elaborate on that?

Comment: It would be common to say  "one thing rather than another"; it's less common to displace the word "rather", giving "rather one thing than another". Not only is it displaced, it's put in the middle of the verb phrase, as "has rather to be seen". All in all, it seems to reach for unusualness at the cost of simplicity and directness.

Answer (score 0):

The translator didn't recognize the idiom *has to* /hastu/, meaning 'must', which can't be separated into *has* and *to* since the words are contracted and pronounced differently, like *used to* /yustu/, meaning 'past but not present tense', which also can't be split up.

This is the sort of thing that happens when written texts are studied without **hearing** them; language is sound, and sounds enter into translation.